# Snowflake having duplicate

Tags: primary-key, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In My use-case, my scheduled Job reads a CSV and writes to snowflake.

When I schedule this read from CSV and write to snowflake for every hour I see multiple duplicates in snowflake. This is despite that my ID is a PRIMARY KEY (ALTER TABLE tablename ADD PRIMARY KEY (column1).

I understand that Snowflake supports defining and maintaining constraints, but does not enforce them, except for NOT NULL constraints, which are always enforced. **I need help to solve this issue.**

To elaborate, Lets consider scenario:

Step 1: At 9AM insert data from CSV to Snowflake
[ID     Customer name   Price
1111    John Mathew     10
1112    David Becham    20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO2fV.png)

Step 2: At 10PM I get one additional row hence my CSV is 
[ID     Customer name   Price
1111    John Mathew     10
1112    David Becham    20
1113    Hello World     40](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ6vu.png)

**Expected in Snowflake**

[ID     Customer name   Price
1111    John Mathew     10
1112    David Becham    20
1113    Hello World     40](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SGwZ.png)

**What I get is duplicates as below**
[ID     Customer name   Price
1111    John Mathew     10
1112    David Becham    20
1113    Hello World     40
1111    John Mathew     10
1112    David Becham    20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Yn8.png)

Comment: Of course you're going to see duplicates if you load a CSV file with the same records multiple times. You would do this in the same way that you would do it in any other database as mike has described below.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provided your code.  It looks like you are updating your CSV, which means Snowflake sees the entire file as a new file to be loaded, which will then load the entire file, again.  If you are just running a `COPY INTO` command with no downstream logic, then that is what will happen.

Two options:

1) don't update the CSV file...just create a new one with just the new data.  Then, the `COPY INTO` command will work fine.

2) if you are also receiving updates to previous records, then you should run a `COPY INTO` into a temporary table and then `MERGE` that data into your final table on the primary key.

Comment: Hi @mike , Can't we use stream logic here.

Comment: You could certainly run the `MERGE` statement in #2 above using a stream, but that is typically for a continuous workstream and/or one where the data being imported is persistently stored.  I suppose if this was hourly as suggested, then using Snowpipe, Stream, and Tasks would be a solution, but the issue here is really how the OP was handling changes to the CSV load.

Answer (score 0):

Create another table(second table) to store de-duplicated records. First table will get data from your source(CSV). Then create a stream on top of first table to capture changes. Then create a task for that stream which will merge(insert/update) data into the second table.